# how can i reverse the order of an array with usestate

Tags: arrays, reactjs, function, use-state

I have connected to an api and have pulled some data into my project with the name of 'data'. This data is being rendered dynamically into a card component. I am now trying to reverse the order of these cards on the click of a button with useState but cannot figure it out. Below is what i have so far:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import './App.scss'
import { useQuery } from '@apollo/react-hooks'
import GET_PRODUCTS_IN_COLLECTION from './gql/getCollection'
import ProductCard from './components/ProductCard/ProductCard'

const App = (props) =>  {

  const {data, loading, error} = useQuery(GET_PRODUCTS_IN_COLLECTION, {
    variables: {
      count: 10,
      handle: 'skateboard'
    }
  })

  const [reverseData, setReverseData] = useState(data)

  const reverseOrder = () => {
    let newArray = reverseData.slice().reverse()
    setReverseData(newArray)
  }
  

  if(loading) {
    // Data is still loading....
    return (<div className="App">Loading....</div>)
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
      </header>
      <main>
        
        <div className="buttonGroup">{reverseData.join(", ")}
          <button onClick={reverseOrder}>Reverse Product Order</button>
          <button>Price High to Low</button>
          <button>Price Low to High</button>
          <button>Display 9 products</button>
          <p>{reverseData}</p>
        </div>

        {/* 
          Your render components go here
        */} 

        <div className="ProductList">
           {data.collectionByHandle.products.edges.map(product => {
             return (<ProductCard productData={product} />)
           })}
        </div>
      </main>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

can someone tell me where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need not store the data fetched via useQuery in the state. Simply store the reversal state, and use that to manipulate the render. If the reversed state is true, use `.slice().reverse()` to reverse you array before render.

```js
const [reversed, setReversed] = useState(false)

const reverseOrder = () => {
  setReversed(!reversed)
}

return (
// ...
    <div className="ProductList">
      {reversed
        ? data.collectionByHandle.products.edges
            .slice()
            .reverse()
            .map((product) => {
              return <ProductCard productData={product} />;
            })
        : data.collectionByHandle.products.edges.map((product) => {
            return <ProductCard productData={product} />;
          })}
    </div>
// ...
)
```

The key here is to reverse the array. In your case the "edges" property seems to be the array. Since reverse changes the array in place, we use slice to create a copy and then reverse, to prevent the original array from being mutated.

Comment: appreciate your help thanks, just abit confused as to where i would use reverseData in my render

Comment: If you're using your state to render something, upon updating the state with a reversed array, the render will be taken care of by React.

It will be helpful to share a simplified version of code you're using to render the products.

Comment: ive updated my coder example in question to show all the code used, when i click the button still no reverse

Comment: when i click the button after updating using your answer, i get 3 errors, 2 of which say: 

'react-dom.development.js:327 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'slice')' 

and the last says:

 Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined

Comment: @Jack updated the answer based on your question edits.

Comment: thanks a lot your way worked! cant thank you enough. can you recommend me to any docs or anything so i can further research this topic.

Comment: MDN (for [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) and [reverse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) i.e. built-in array methods)

The best documentation for React is the official [documentation](https://reactjs.org/). 

I think the rest of it is just using React & JS and just getting familiar with it all. Of course, Stackoverflow is one of the best places to ask specific questions. Sometimes serves as the unofficial docs.

Comment: thanks pal really appreciate your time, i've got 3 other buttons to do which i will get on my own now you have helped

Comment: could you possibly help me with another question related to this question?

Comment: @Jack Sure, add a new question and link it here

Comment: i've got the last button working however i cant figure out how to write my sort method. I'm guessing this is the right method for the middle 2 buttons, but i'm Just not writing it properly?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71198330/15605631

Answer (score 1):

`.reverse()` mutates the array, and you shouldn't mutate `useState` values directly. Instead of this you need to create the new value:

```
  const reverseOrder = () => {
    let newArray = [...reverseData]
    newArrray.reverse()
    setReverseData(newArray)
  }
```

So, you create a new array from your state, mutate it and assign to the state

Comment: thanks. I've just made the changes as you suggested but still nothing happens when i click the button. Is it something to do with what is passed into usestate itself 'useState([data])' ?

Comment: could you show please where you use your `reverseData`? You could update your question

Comment: sure, one minute

Comment: updated it for you

Comment: I guess you should use `useState(data)` instead of `useState([data])`. Where do you use `reverseData ` in your render?

Comment: ahh i think thats my problem haha where would use this?

Comment: just replace `const [reverseData, setReverseData] = useState([data])` to `const [reverseData, setReverseData] = useState(data)`

Comment: I've replaced this, still not working haha confused. ive updated my question to show whole code, i need to add reverseData to the render somewhere i think but do not know where

Comment: You should render it something like this: `{reverseData.map(item => <div>{item.name}</div>)}`